# cs:go how to get item seed (paintseed) from offical steam api?

Tags: steam, seed, steam-web-api

I cannot find how to get item seed (paintseed) from steam api.
I have id, market name and float (wear) of an item. I got them on skinbaron api.
Using https://csgofloat.com to get seed is bad option because i heard that it's unstable api.
Does anyone know how to get that paintseed on offical steam api ?